# Javascript Callback with Parameters and Return Value

Tags: javascript, callback

Here is my dilemma, I have a series of functions that get called and I am using callbacks to execute a function when they are complete.  The callback returns a value and that works great too, my problem is when I add parameters to the callback I can no longer access the returned value.  Here is an example what works:

```
function myFunc1(x, y) {
   /*do stuff*/
   myFunc2(z, callback);
}

function callback(results) {
   alert(results);  /*this works!*/
}
```

This works great, the results returned are displayed.  My problem what I need to do is something like this:

```
function myFunc1(x, y) {
   /*do stuff*/
   myFunc2(z, callback(x,y));
}

function callback(x,y,results) {
   alert(x);        /*works!*/
   alert(y);        /*works!*/
   alert(results);  /*doesn't work :(*/
}
```

I need a way to access both the value return as well as my parameters.  Is something like this possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to not call the `callback` immediately, but instead make a function that calls `callback` later with the expected arguments:

```
function myFunc1(x, y) {
    /*do stuff*/
    myFunc2(z, function(results) {
        callback(x, y, results);
    });
}
```

The [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) variant proposed by @thefourtheye is basically<sup>1</sup> a shortcut for this function expression.

<sub>1: rather for `function(results) { return callback.call(null, x, y, results) }`, also it would pass through more arguments than only `results`, and it would evaluate `x` and `y` at the time of the `bind` call.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), like this

```
myFunc2(z, callback.bind(null, x, y));
```

`bind` function will return a new function with the first parameter as the context and the next parameters are the actual parameters passed to `callback` when invoked.